# Delphi unrar.dll reports wrong packed size

Tags: delphi, rar

Using winrar's freeware unrar.dll for apps: http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm and XE7

> UnRAR.dll UnRAR dynamic library for Windows software developers

When I list a rar contents (list of files inside it) the filenames are correct, however the reported size is always 0. Their own Delphi demo does this as well, I suspect it was made very long ago with a much older version of Delphi.

After calling RARReadHeaderEx(hArcData, HeaderData), HeaderData UnpSize/UnpSizeHigh (UINT) should contain the file size, but both values are always 0 after the call.

What's wrong?

You can find the delphi demo in the link above, although it needs a small modification for it to work:

```
OpenArchiveData.ArcName    := ArcName;
```

this must be

```
OpenArchiveData.ArcName    := NIL;   
OpenArchiveData.ArcNameW   := PChar(ArcName);
```

Comment: Why are you setting NIL to string type? I haven't tested it out since I'm not on my dev machine but this could be the cause.

Comment: Not a direct answer to you problem just a workaround: Else you could consider useing 7Zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the DLL itself has no problem at all, if you Download the Delphi component wrapper from [this link](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/RARComponent_12.zip), install it and try to open the demo, once you will open a RAR file you will get size of the files inside correctly :

[image: Example]

So, I can say that the `Delphi component wrapper for UnRar.dll by Philippe Wechsler` is fully working and compatible with Delphi XE7 (just install the D2009 package).

Comment: Thanks, found the issue thanks to his code, ArcName and Filename must be AnsiChar rather than Char, that fixed it.